# How to use angular with php

Tags: angular, xampp

I've a question to use angular with php is necessary to put all the php file in the same angular project ??? Or all the php files They had to be only inside the xampp folder www.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Angular and PHP files are all inside the webroot, you're fine. The Angular frontend and the PHP backend should be decoupled, and the directory structure relative to each other will not matter.

Comment: So, of your answer I understand that the files php can be inside the xammp/www and the frond-end in then angular project?

Comment: If you go to the config file at `xampp/apache/conf/http.conf` and look for the DocumentRoot setting, that is the directory that all of your web-accessible files (PHP, Angular, whatever) need to be located in. You can change this setting, if you like. Other than that, the PHP and Angular directory structures can (and really should) remain separate.